# Putting Debian 7.3 on a USB drive via the dd command

Tags: usb, partitioning, debian, dd

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask this, but I assumed as it's pertaining to the `dd` command it would be.

Normally to do this I'd use the Windows application [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) but per Debian's FAQ, it recommends using the `dd` command (plus UUI requires either the netinst or live ISO, neither of which I care to use), so I gave that a shot.

Here are the steps I took:

1 - Formatted the entire drive with an MBR.

2 - Created a FAT32 partition (entire drive)

I figured I'd start with these, as a new USB drive would probably be the same.

**Result:** Went perfectly.

3 - `dd if=<ISO> of=/dev/sdb bs=4M; sync`

```
155+1 records in
155+1 records out
652214272 bytes (652 MB) copied, 264.895 s, 2.5 MB/s
```

4 - Looked at the device in Debian's Disk Utility.

**Result:** The "partitioning" had changed from "Master Boot Record" to "Unknown Scheme:" - On top of that, I can no longer mount the filesystem, which I understand, as apparently the MBR is gone...I tried the same with `/dev/sdb1` and instead, the partition's "usage" went from "Filesystem" to "--" as if the filesystem got corrupted.

I have no idea what's causing this, so any help getting it to work as expected would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you do not need to format the disk beforehand: dd'ing an image to disk implies wiping out its whole content first (done by dd itself!), then copying the iso image record by record on the disk. This means that the iso image (as the word says) already contains an MBR and all that is necessary for properly booting. The pre-dd disk needs neither a partition table, nor formatting.

2) Did you **unmount** the stick before dd'ing it? That is very important.

3) the correct command is the one you used, **not** the one with the partition */dev/sdb1*. As soon as you dd a disk, all partitions are gone, so it makes no sense to reference one, nor to keep the stick mounted.

4) if you experience problems, you may try to reduce the block size. bs=1M might suit you. It is just a tad slower.

Comment: Aha! So that's what the ISO-9660 meant. I just thought it messed up somehow. (Sorry for the late reply, been playing Minecraft. I could've sworn comments/answers showed up in the top panel...Maybe that's only if you have an account.) @MariusMatutiae - 1. Awesome info, thank you. 2. Yes. I disable the automatic mount startup item.   3. I thought so, but I figured I'd try anyway. :P -- I'll give it another go and see if it boots (which I should've done in hindsight, but I thought this was odd, so I decided to ask first).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the "hybrid" ISO image. They contain both an ISO-9660 (CD-ROM) filesystem and a "regular" partition layout for USB drives, so they can be written to an USB-stick using "dd" or to a CD using any writing tool.

You can find the "hybrid" images here: http://www.debian.org/CD/live/

If you want to use one of the other ISOs, it's probably easiest to use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to write them to the USB stick.